# How to get last timestamp in array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, timestamp, local-storage

Hello I am having trouble getting my timestamp to not always update in previous rows. I was using Date.now() and it would update previous rows in my html table. So I decided to put all dates in array and replace it and have var as myDate, if that makes sense however I am having trouble doing that and how to proceed. How would I achieve this or is there an better solution to go about this?

this is my current code for creating timestamp array:

```
        var data = [];
        data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session')) || [];
        // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the array
        data.push( Date.now() );
        localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(data));
        myDate = date;

        //inputed data
        time = myDate;
```

Comment: `myDate = date` should perhaps be `myDate = data[data.length-1]`?

Comment: how about `myDate = Date.now()` then `data.push(myDate)` - since the last timestamp is the one you're pushing - or even `data.push( myDate = Date.now() )`

Comment: It seems to show the same time everytime